# Bootstrap 4 tooltip only showing when specifying HTML attributes -

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

It's a problem that's not as easy to reproduce with a fiddle. I have a classic Bootstrap 4 page but i can only get the tooltip to show if i put the HTML data-attributes manually.

Doing it with javascript doesn't seem to work - What's more, using javascript to create the .tooltip on any element (either data-toggle="tooltip" or even by class or element doesn't work either). This is the function i'm using in a  underneath the page:

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        container: 'body',
        placement: 'bottom',
        title: 'test'
    })

});
```

Adding the data-toggle, data-title, data-placement as usual in the HTML works but i'd like to have everything in a single function call. 
I've double-checked:

- loading order [jquery/tether/bootstrap]
- the tooltip is applied to a button with data-toggle="tooltip" [nothing else]
- the element with data-toggle attribute [a button] is correctly identified and selected on page load.

using Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 loaded locally

Comment: Are you sure the `data-toggle` attribute is still present your HTML? I'm asking this because your jQuery selector uses it.

Comment: yes, double-checked that a few times; it works if i add the rest of the attributes [aka it shows] but i want to load the tooltip through the function which doesn't seem to work

Comment: Does showing the tooltip programmatically work? I.e. `$('[data-toggle]').tooltip('show');`

Comment: @JasonK it doesn't work either... what could this be? You have an extra bracket on [data-toggle""]"" i tried with the usual $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]') selector

Comment: Put a debugger keywrod before the tooltip line and check that $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').length is 1

Comment: tony i added the debugger and it's length 1

Comment: @tony i tried calling the tooltip() while paused on debugger but still nothing. also added tooltip().show() as per Jason K's comment. it's pissing me off

Comment: You could probably step into the bootstrap code to find the issue

Comment: I wonder if it's there but off the page for some reason, especially since you say you can't reproduce it in a fiddle. You could try wiring into the show event to find out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151045/discussion-between-vzr-and-tony).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discussion revealed that both Bootstrap and Jquery UI were being used, there was a conflict between the two tooltips. Changing the order of the links was sufficient to fix it